# file command misclassifying python bytecode as dBase III DBT file

Tags: python, file-command

I'm using cx-Freeze to freeze a PyQt5 application. On my Jenkins slave running OSX 10.13, when cx-Freeze is using the file command to check the type of the files, it classifies a .pyc file (python bytecode) as a dBase III DBT file with some non-utf-8 characters in the output:

```
$>file ./__pycache__/archive_util.cpython-35.opt-2.pyc
./__pycache__/archive_util.cpython-35.opt-2.pyc: dBase III DBT, version number 0, next free block index 168627479, 1st item "N)?warn)?DistutilsExecError)?spawn)?mkpath)?log)getpwnam)getgrnamc"
```

When I run the file command on the same file on my own Mac OS, I get the correct classification:

```
$>file ./__pycache__/archive_util.cpython-35.opt-2.pyc
./__pycache__/archive_util.cpython-35.opt-2.pyc: python 3.5.2+ byte-compiled
```

What could possibly make `file` command to behave that way in the Jenkins build machine?

Comment: File actually just guesses based on a database of heuristics. Dont rely on it to be right.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a different version of the `file` command with a different magic file `/usr/share/file/magic.mgc` (see the source files `/usr/share/file/magic/database` for the "dBase III" definitions and `/usr/share/file/magic/python` for python) or your pyc files are different (different python version and/or code) and `file` has a false match on Jenkins.

Have you compared the files or swapped them and run `file` on them again? If both files are the same, it must be a different `magic.mgc` file (or if it is missing different source files or a different configuration like a `MAGIC` environment variable, but that's not very likely).